# IPython notebook error opening after trying to pip install pycloud on Anaconda

Tags: pip, ipython, anaconda

I was using IPython notebook from the command prompt Anaconda to make a word cloud but had to get some modules. ctrl -c'd to import.. then using the following advice from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytagcloud I did the following

```
pip install simplejson

pip install -U pytagcloud

easy_install -U pytagcloud
```

And now I can't open my IPython notebook. The first error I get is:

```
lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi__x7f4cf786x6096cf31.c:185:1
7: fatal error: zmq.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Then Traceback displays

```
File "C:\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\zmqrelated.py" line 35 in check_for_zmq

File "C:\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py, line 49
```

And more

Also, pip install is having issues now.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: solved the issue by removing the folders from my site-packages directory.